# Custom dialog using JOptionPane API won't dispose

Tags: java, swing, dispose, joptionpane

I've been just playing with [JOptionPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) API to show a custom dialog and I've found a strange situation: when I choose either <kbd>OK</kbd> or <kbd>Cancel</kbd> option or press <kbd>Esc</kbd> key this dialog won't dispose as expected.

The thing is, instead of using this single line to display a modal dialog:

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog( null
                            , "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
                            , "New Dialog"
                            , JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION
                            , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

I wanted to use the API, setting all the parameters one by one and displaying a dialog as shown in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) (see ***Direct Use*** section):

```
 JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(arguments);
 pane.set.Xxxx(...); // Configure
 JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(parentComponent, title);
 dialog.show();
```

However, when I close the dialog my application keeps running, even if I set the default close operation to [`DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html#DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE), and it makes me suspect the dialog is not properly disposed.

Below is a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to play with:

```
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane();
                optionPane.setMessage("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.");
                optionPane.setOptionType(JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                optionPane.setMessageType(JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

                JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog("New Dialog");
                dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, inspecting [JOptionPane#createDialog(String title)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#createDialog-java.lang.String-) source code, it turns out the dialog is not closed nor disposed but hidden instead, and it's done on a `PropertyChangeEvent` when the option pane's value is set (to `CANCEL_OPTION` or `NO_OPTION` or `CLOSED_OPTION` I guess):

```
public class JOptionPane extends JComponent implements Accessible {

    ...

     // The following method is called within 'createDialog(...)'
     // in order to initialize the JDialog that will be retrieved.

    private void initDialog(final JDialog dialog, int style, Component parentComponent) {
        ...
        final PropertyChangeListener listener = new PropertyChangeListener() {
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
                // Let the defaultCloseOperation handle the closing
                // if the user closed the window without selecting a button
                // (newValue = null in that case).  Otherwise, close the dialog.
                if (dialog.isVisible() && event.getSource() == JOptionPane.this &&
                        (event.getPropertyName().equals(VALUE_PROPERTY)) &&
                        event.getNewValue() != null &&
                        event.getNewValue() != JOptionPane.UNINITIALIZED_VALUE) {
                    dialog.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        };

        WindowAdapter adapter = new WindowAdapter() {
            private boolean gotFocus = false;
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                setValue(null);
            }

            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
                dialog.getContentPane().removeAll();
            }

            public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent we) {
                // Once window gets focus, set initial focus
                if (!gotFocus) {
                    selectInitialValue();
                    gotFocus = true;
                }
            }
        };
        dialog.addWindowListener(adapter);
        dialog.addWindowFocusListener(adapter);
        ...
    }
}
```

Despite the comment that states *"Otherwise, close the dialog"*, no [WindowEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowEvent.html) closing the dialog is even fired. Consequently the dialog won't be disposed properly unless we explicitely do so:

```
    JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog("New Dialog");
    dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    dialog.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(dialog, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```

Please note on a [`WINDOW_CLOSING`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowEvent.html#WINDOW_CLOSING) event the [WindowListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) attached to the dialog within `initDialog(...)` method will just set the option pane's value to `null` but still won't dispose the dialog. That's why we still need to set the default close operation to [`DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html#DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE).

Comment: JOptionPane is derived part from JDialog, I'm sure good explanations (and relevant code) is here a few times in posts by @kleopatra

Comment: dialog.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(dialog, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING)); == terminating current JVM, are you sure with ...,

Comment: @mKorbel: 1) Thanks! I didn't think about it. I'll take a look at kleopatra's posts. 2) In this case, yes, it will terminate the current JVM because there are no more windows (JFrame not JDialog) but it's only for purposes of example.