# java EventQueue throwing error

Tags: java, swing

i'm trying to create a simple login application

here is my code

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {

        Login dialog = new Login(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
        dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter(){

            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e){
            System.exit(0);
            }
       }); 
        dialog.setVisible(true);

    });
```

and i got red line in the first line of the code and its saying "illegal start of expression"

i tried hard and ddnt figure it out yet, please help me out.

Comment: Please include a [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing your problem. As is your code seems correct.

Comment: @dic19 can you tell how to include the MCVE ??

Comment: See the one included [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27404362/1795530): a main class with the minimal lines of code needed to reproduce the problem. So other developers can just copy and paste the example and run it.

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling with JDK 8?  This would be illegal syntax on Java 7 and earlier.

Comment: @IanMcLaird so that's the problem i'm using Java 7